# Streaming a xls file in zope

Tags: python, zope, zope3

I'm having troubles using zope.
I just need to serve to the client a xls file created with python xlwt module but I don't find the way to do that.

In my .pt file I have a button that calls a .py function, this function creates correctly the file, but it doesn't serve it to the client browser.
I'm trying in this way:

```
f = open(temp_file, 'rb').read()
self.request.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel')
self.request.response.setHeader('Content-Disposition',' attachment; filename=Excel_Workbook.xls')
return f
```

How can I do that?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Are you open to using a browser view to do this?  I do this with a browser view and a custom "file stream iterator" that uses (and disposes of when done) temp files.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the script? You need to invoke it directly from a URL, not from your template.

Include a download URL in your template that *points* to your python script:

```html
<a href="http://yoursite/path/to/script">Download an Excel spreadsheet</a>
```